# concurrent.futures: to run multiple task at the same time

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

Below, I'm try to use the Python futures module to run 2 functions at the same time. However, 
I'm getting error `future._condition.acquire() AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '_condition'`

Did I used the futures module correctly?

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

def f1():
    print ("1")
    return ('a')

def f2():
    return 'b'

executors_list = []
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    executors_list.append(f1)
    executors_list.append(f2)

for future in as_completed(executors_list):
    r = (future.result())
    print("r: ".format(r))
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Need to use `executor.submit(f1)`

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

def f1():
    return ('a')

def f2():
    return 'b'

executors_list = []
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    to_do = [executor.submit(f1),
             executor.submit(f2)]

    for future in as_completed(to_do):
        print("future: {}, result {} ".format(future, future.result()))
```